# How to install subversion on shared hosting account?

Tags: svn, hosting, centos5

I'd like to install subversion on my web hosting account. I have access to ssh, running Apache 2, and CentOS 5 as the operating system.

How can I do this? Any ideas?

Comment: Starting with http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.html, where do you see problems and what are your specific questions? Do you plan to allow anonymous access, authenticated access from multiple users (trusted or not?) or just for yourself?

Answer (score 1):

Which hosting are you using? I recently tried doing the same thing with Hostgator, but unfortunately they don't allow it. Consider using hosted solutions like GIT etc.